# How to show uncompressed total physical size in bytes of an HFS-compressed file or directory?

Tags: macos, command-line, compression, hfs+, du

Case in point: Apple's TextEdit at `/Applications/TextEdit.app`

If you calculate the physical size with `echo "$(/usr/bin/du -k -d 0 /Applications/TextEdit.app | /usr/bin/awk '{print $1}') * 1024" | /usr/bin/bc -l` you'll get (in my case on 10.11.6) a size of **4538368 bytes**.

However, if you open the Info window in Finder, it'll tell you that the physical size is way bigger: **8.6 MB on disk**, almost double the size.

It's clear why: Apple used HFS compression on TextEdit. Running the third-party tool **afsctool** (which you can install with Homebrew) produces this result:

`/usr/local/bin/afsctool /Applications/TextEdit.app
/Applications/TextEdit.app:
Number of HFS+ compressed files: 693`

Now, macOS obviously seems to know the uncompressed physical size, as evidenced by the size-on-disk value in the Finder's Info window.

My question is, if there is a command-line read-only way to get that info, i.e. a way to show:

(a) the **uncompressed physical size** (disk use) of a file that is HFS-compressed, i.e. a file for which `/usr/bin/stat -f %f` returns "32" (even though it's "524320" for some reason in TextEdit), and

(b) the **uncompressed total physical size** (disk use) of a directory or bundle that contains HFS compressed files.

**Note:** only macOS native commands should be used to calculate the size, while *not* using Spotlight-dependent data, e.g. from the `mdls` command, which is buggy and sometimes returns `(null)` for the `kMDItemPhysicalSize` key, aside from the fact that some users have disabled Spotlight altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`afsctool`](https://github.com/RJVB/afsctool) command with `-v` flag, for example:

```
$ afsctool -v README
README:
File is HFS+ compressed.
File size (uncompressed data fork; reported size by Mac OS 10.6+ Finder): 3046 bytes / 3 KB (kilobytes) / 3 KiB (kibibytes)
File size (compressed data fork - decmpfs xattr; reported size by Mac OS 10.0-10.5 Finder): 0 bytes / 0 KB (kilobytes) / 0 KiB (kibibytes)
File size (compressed data fork): 1427 bytes / 1 KB (kilobytes) / 1 KiB (kibibytes)
Compression savings: 53.2%
Number of extended attributes: 0
Total size of extended attribute data: 0 bytes
Approximate overhead of extended attributes: 268 bytes
Approximate total file size (compressed data fork + EA + EA overhead + file overhead): 1943 bytes / 2 KB (kilobytes) / 2 KiB (kibibytes)
```

Comment: I wonder why afsctool was removed from macOS!  
Ideas: Can it be copied from an old install? Is it in Darwin?

Answer (score 0):

Well, `afsctool` was removed from macOS, and `du` works on entire directories:

```
  %  ditto -v --hfsCompression  --arch arm64 /Volumes/Thunderbird/Thunderbird.app \
     /Applications/Thunderbird\ BETA\ V.99.ARM64.app
Copying /Volumes/Thunderbird/Thunderbird.app [arm64]

 %  ditto -v --hfsCompression  /Volumes/Thunderbird/Thunderbird.app
    /Applications/Thunderbird\ BETA\ V.99.UNIVERSAL.app 
Copying /Volumes/Thunderbird/Thunderbird.app 

  % du -sk /Applications/Thunderbird* /Volumes/Thunderbird/Thunderbird.app                                              
352808  /Applications/Thunderbird BETA V.94.Universal.app
74832   /Applications/Thunderbird BETA V.99.ARM64.app
133152  /Applications/Thunderbird BETA V.99.UNIVERSAL.app
349184  /Applications/Thunderbird.app
349184  /Volumes/Thunderbird/Thunderbird.app

 % du -skA /Applications/Thunderbird\ BETA\ V.99.*
207938  /Applications/Thunderbird BETA V.99.ARM64.app
348917  /Applications/Thunderbird BETA V.99.UNIVERSAL.app
 %
```

From the documentation :

du:     `-A`      Display the apparent size instead of the disk usage.  This can be helpful when operating on compressed volumes or
sparse files

(I wonder why and when afsctool was removed from macOS, if it can be copied from an old install, and if it is in Darwin.)

Oh, and as for mdls, this works better with the sleep:

```
% cat /dev/urandom | head -c 5 > foo; sleep 3; mdls foo | grep ize
kMDItemFSSize                          = 5
kMDItemLogicalSize                     = 5
kMDItemPhysicalSize                    = 4096
```

vs

```
% cat /dev/urandom | head -c 2 > foo; mdls foo | grep ize
kMDItemFSSize              = (null)
```

Also, the output depends on the current directory; it acts differently in /tmp vs ~.